# How to record a screencast with audio in gnome shell

Tags: sound, gnome, screencast

I'm trying to change my configuration so that the default <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> also records audio. I've used this code:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.recorder pipeline "queue ! videorate ! vp8enc quality=10 speed=2 ! mux. pulsesrc ! audio/x-raw-int ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! mux. webmmux name=mux"
```

In my console, and it works ok, it just doesn't stop once I hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> again.

Any help would rock!

Comment: This isn't an answer, but here's the upstream bug for this issue, including comments on the audio-doesn't-stop issue: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665548

Comment: @Costa has this problem been solved? Is it still a problem for you? When you posted this question 5+ years ago it was about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL or another EOL version of Ubuntu. I wanted to flag your question as `not reproducible` but would like your input first. Thanks.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix I would love it if this worked, but it still doesn't. I'm happy to retry, but it requires a restart. Let me know if you need that. I'm on 14.04 now.

Comment: @Costa I'm not sure why you need to restart. Can't you test in Ubuntu 14.04 and reword the question as needing it to work under 14.04? This way the question is no longer about Ubuntu 12.04 which is EOL. I don't use `screencast` so cannot help you solve the problem. I'm just on a project to close unanswered questions for EOL Ubuntu versions.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix okay, so right now on my system (14.04 gnome ubuntu) `ctrl` + `alt` + `shift` + `R` starts and stops screen recording, but doesn't record any audio from the microphone or from the system (like playing a YouTube video during the screen recording for example).

Comment: @Costa So 12.04 is better in the sense that it starts sound recording. The problem still remains where you cant stop recording in 12.04?

Comment: No idea. I'm not on 12.04 anymore. What I wanted was to have audio and video recorded with those hotkeys. Would have been nice.

Comment: The [old bug](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=665548) is now followed on [GitLab](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5524) (maybe also [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-shell/-/issues/5524)). Unfortunately, a GNOME dev only points us using to use [EasyScreenCast](https://github.com/EasyScreenCast/EasyScreenCast)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative is to use this Gnome Extension [EasyScreenCast](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/690/easyscreencast/), it uses gnome-shell's screencast

It handles audio and many more options

You need to choose what *audio source* to record from, as shown here:

[image]

Comment: I think the user (as well as myself) would like to make the tool to record the sound the computer produces - the one that comes out. Hence the answer will be more informational if it'd tell that in the example of the screenshot, one should choose the output port to use.

Comment: @DoronBehar In the screenshot above, I have 2 of them, *Built-in...* and *GK104...*, which respectively are, my motherBoard's jack audio ouput, and my HDMI connected TV. If I connect my microphone, then it becomes a third option available to choose from. So in other words, the sources displayed in that list, are all the *inputs (microphones)* and the *outputs (speakers)* available in your system.

Comment: Done!, sorry I misunderstood your comment twice!