# Recording in GNOME stopped working after gsettings editing

Tags: gnome, sound, recordmydesktop, sound-recorder

I was looking for a way to record audio with video on Gnome Shell (Ubuntu 13.04) and after doing these command:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.shell.recorder pipeline "queue ! videorate ! vp8enc quality=10 speed=2 ! mux. pulsesrc ! audio/x-raw-int ! queue ! audioconvert ! vorbisenc ! mux. webmmux name=mux"
```

Recording stopped working. I found this solution [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112473/audio-not-working-for-gnome-screencast-ctrl-alt-shift-r).

Any help would be nice.

Comment: Problem reproduced here: 1. Before setting the pipeline mentioned above, recording works but without audio. 2. After setting the custom pipeline, `Ctrl+Alt+Shift+R` no longer does anything (no bottom-right green/red indicator and no file created). 3. Reverting the default value (`gsettings reset org.gnome.shell.recorder pipeline`)restores the initial behavior

Comment: [Possible duplicate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/157676/how-to-record-a-screencast-with-audio-in-gnome-shell).