# How to configure the default recorder to record the voice too?

Tags: audio-recording, desktop-recording, video-recording

In a Laptop Toshiba with Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 (No Virtualbox involved) - when is pressed the <kbd>print screen</kbd> key is possible to either take a screenshot or record a video - it for a custom selection, the complete screen and finally for a specific window. And well, there is a red circle to start the process. It is for the default software/tool loaded by Ubuntu.

Even when is possible to record the video as `.webm` by default and play it with either the default tool or VLC, there is **no** audio, therefore the input is ignored. If is reached `Settings -> Sound -> Input`, I can confirm the `Input Device` works as expected. It by simply saying some words.

**Question**

How to configure this default recorder to record the voice too?

Comment: You can't do that, even though it has been discussed on this website for [at least ten years](https://askubuntu.com/questions/112473/audio-not-working-for-gnome-screencast-ctrl-alt-shift-r). Use a different program.

Comment: Interesting this situation ....